How can I view my voting history on Quora?
A few days ago I went to my Quora profile and l saw that my activity had disappeared. For example, I no longer see my voting history on other users' posts and answers which is only listed in my activity.
Other things still remained such as my questions, followers, and edits.
The last time I was in Quora was in January and my activity was still there.
I have confirmed that my voting history still exists on the platform by looking at some of the Quora posts I upvoted and had bookmarked in my browser and they still show my upvote.
I don't know why I am no longer seeing this activity. I contacted Quora moderators but they couldn't help me.
Is there a way to restore this missing activity on Quora or see it?

@ThomasWard I don't see why. This question can easily be transformed into an on-topic one (see my suggested edit).

Can you confirm that on Quora's stats page you have the filter set to "All Time" (see example image)

@Blindspots yes l have it in all time though l am in mobile phone l don't know if this makes any difference

Please test from a web browser. You need to be accessing a web app  (in a web browser) to be on topic for this site (looks like you sorted out the account )

If you use the Quora app on your mobile device let me know whether it's Android or iOS and I can migrate this to the correct site.

I am using quora web browser(not app)on android

Per Can I get a copy of my data? - Quora Help Center, you can request an export of all your activity data by visiting quora.com/contact (currently a redirect to this page) and selecting "I want a copy of my data". You can also email the privacy@quora.com address.
This will provide your Quora data in a machine-readable format. At time of writing, you'll receive some XML (masquerading as invalid HTML) that looks something like this. (Linebreaks and indentation inserted by me.)
<html>
 <div>
  <h1>Recent Pageviews</h1>
  <p>
   <h2>Recent Pageview</h2>
   <div><strong>Ip: </strong><span>127.0.0.1</span></div>
   <div><strong>User-agent: </strong><span>Ya me neither, you guys want to go skateboards?</span></div>
   <div><strong>Referrer: </strong><span>http://localhost:1337/</span></div>
   <div><strong>Url: </strong><span>https://www.quora.com/unanswered/Whats-your-favorite-ASDF-movie</span></div>
   <div><strong>Time: </strong><span>Sep 18, 2024 12:34 AM PDT</span></div>
  </p>
  <hr />
  <p>
   <h2>Recent Pageview</h2>
   <div><strong>Ip: </strong><span>172.31.255.255</span></div>
   <div><strong>User-agent: </strong><span>A cylinder, 30 yards across, glowing hot</span></div>
   <div><strong>Referrer: </strong><span /></div>
   <div><strong>Url: </strong><span>https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-chances-of-something-coming-from-Mars?share=1</span></div>
   <div><strong>Time: Jan 18, 2038 08:14 PM PST</strong></div>
  </p>
  <hr />
 </div>
 <div>
  <h1>Answer Upvotes</h1>
  <p>
   <h2>Answer Upvote</h2>
   <div><strong>Answer: </strong><span>https://www.quora.com/Do-you-believe-that-the-cake-is-a-lie/answer/Brandon-R-380</span></div>
   <div><strong>Time: </strong><span>Jul 05, 2024 11:40 AM PST</span></div>
   <div><strong>Content language: </strong><span>English</span></div>
  </p>
  <hr />
 </div>
 <div>
  <h1>Answer Downvotes</h1>
...


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
